# Difference between two similar DSL queries in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl, nest

I'm producing a DSL query to execute against Elasticsearch using Nest. The search phrase provided by the end user is splitted by blank spaces and then passed to construct the query.

[image]

The DSL query output depends on how many words are passed to BuildQuery method. If is a single word the query looks like this:

[image]

But if more than one words are passed the output is more complex query and each word is inserted in a separate *multi_match*.

[image]

I was playing with the query and found that I can simplify it by inserting the entire text in a single *multi_match* like this.

[image]

No matter how the query is constructed it returns the same result and the same score.

My question is what's the difference between the simplified query with the single *multi_match* that contains the entire text without being splitted and the more complex query where every word is in a separate *multi_match*?

Which one query is better and why?

May I simplify my code and be sure everything will work smoothly even with more complex queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like the only difference is going to come down to the analyzer used on each of the fields included in the `multi_match` query.

#### Many multi_match queries in bool should clauses

Where you split the text on whitespace and construct a disjunction of `multi_match` most_fields queries on each *term*, the term passed will be analyzed by the analyzer of each field to produce a token, a relevancy score calculated based on TF/IDF (or BM25 by default in Elasticsearch 5.0+) for each token and a total score calculated by the sum of scores from each `should` clause divided by the number of `should` clauses.

#### Single multi_match query

Where you pass the text to on `multi_match` query, the text passed will be analyzed by the analyzer of each field as before; I suspect you have an analyzer that tokenizes on whitespace characters (probably using the default [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html), which tokenizes based on [Unicode Text Segmentation](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/)) to produce multiple tokens, a relevancy score calculated for each token. and a total score calculated by the sum of scores for each token divided by the number of match clauses.